# Problems using readline method with nested while loops Python

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, readline

I am trying to write a code that will take a .txt file containing words and their definitions and produce a dictionary of {'word1':['definition1', 'definition2'...]}. The .txt file is in the following format:

word1

definition1

definition2

(blank line)

word2

definition1

definition2
...

so far the body of the function I have written is as follows:

```
line = definition_file.readline()
dictx = {}

while line != '':
    key = line.strip()
    defs = []
    line = definition_file.readline()
    while line != '\n':
        defx = [line.strip()]
        defs += defx
        line = definition_file.readline()
    if key not in dictx:
    dictx[key] = defs

return dictx
```

I quickly realized the problem with this code is that it will only return a dictionary with the very first word within it. I need a way to make the code loop so that it returns a dictionary with all the words + definitions. I was hoping to do this **without using a break**.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
is_definition = False

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().rstrip('\n')
        if line == '':                     # blank line
            is_definition=False
            continue
        if is_definition:                  # definition line
            d[word].append(line)
        else:                              # word line
            word = line
            is_definition = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will also do the trick:

```
>>> tesaurus = open('tesaurus.txt').read()
>>> dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].split()), [term.split("\n", 1) for term in tesaurus.replace("\r", "").split("\n\n")]))
{'word1': ['definition1', 'definition2'], 'word3': ['def1', 'def2'], 'word2': ['definition1', 'definition2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility:

```
d = dict()
defs = list()
with open('test.txt') as infile:
   for line in infile:
       if not line:
            d[defs[0]] = defs[1:]
            defs = list()
       else:
            defs.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file

```
d = dict()
with open('file.txt') as f:
    stuff = f.read()
```

Split the file on blank lines.

```
word_defs = stuff.split('\n\n')
```

Iterate over the definition groups and split the word from the definitions.

```
for word_def in word_defs:
    word_def = word_def.split('\n')
    word = word_def[0]
    defs = word_def[1:]
    d[word] = defs
```

---

If you prefer something more *functional* /compact (same thing but different). First an iterator that produces `[word, def, def, ...]` groups.

```
definition_groups = (thing.split('\n') for thing in stuff.split('\n\n'))
```

dict comprehension to build the dictionary

```
import operator
word = operator.itemgetter(0)
defs = operator.itemgetter(slice(1,None))
g = {word(group):defs(group) for group in definition_groups}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best answer that meets your criteria.

```
import sys

d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    done = False
    while not done:
        word = f.readline().strip()
        done = not word

        line = True
        defs = []
        while line:
            line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            if line.strip():
                defs.append(line)
        if not done:
            d[word] = defs
print(d)
```

But I don't understand why you are trying to avoid using `break`.  I think this code is clearer with `break`... the flow of control is simpler and we don't need as many variables.  When `word` is an empty string, this code just breaks out (immediately stops what it is doing) and that is very easy to understand.  You have to study the first code to make sure you know how it works when end-of-file is reached.

```
import sys

d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    while True:
        word = f.readline().strip()
        defs = []
        if not word:
            break

        while True:
            line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            if not line:
                break
            defs.append(line)
        d[word] = defs
print(d)
```

But I think the best way to write this is to make a helper function that packages up the job of parsing out the definitions:

```
import sys

def _read_defs(f):
    while True:
        line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
        if not line:
            break
        yield line

d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    while True:
        word = f.readline().strip()
        if not word:
            break
        d[word] = list(_read_defs(f))
print(d)
```

The first one is trickier because it is avoiding the use of `break`.  The others are simpler to understand, with two similar loops that have similar flow of control.